# How are you suppose to NAT with snow leopard server mini with only 1 ethernet port?

Tags: networking, nat, mac-osx-server, ethernet

How are you suppose to NAT with snow leopard server mini with only 1 ethernet port?

Comment: Use vLans. You should consider visiting some of your old questions an marking answers correct if they are.

Comment: Shouldn't it work out of the box?? Apple designed this!

Answer (score 3):

Set up 2 or more VLANs on the ethernet port.
Use a managed switch to break these VLANs out onto physical ports.  That way, you could have non-nat traffic on VLAN 2, and natted private RFC1918 traffic on VLAN 3, all shared on the same physical ethernet port.

Gotta love 802.11q...

Answer (score 0):

You can use NAT with Ethernet and AirPort.

Comment: Ugh. Servers on WiFi.. That's just destined to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Use NAT to bridge the ethernet access to a FireWire LAN. I've done it ;). Performance isn't great, but you can blame the IPoFW implementation for that.

Answer (score 0):

Or pick up a USB->Ethernet adapter.

Answer (score 0):

While VLANs are probably the best solution, NAT on a stick (sometimes called 'loopback NAT') works just fine. It doesn't provide the same security as traditional NAT, but most people are using NAT to *provide* access not to prevent it. Essentially, your inside and outside subnets just live on the same Ethernet segment.